# How do I add an arrow to point to the submenus in the horizontal menu that came with VS?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, menu

I'm using just the standard template that comes with Visual Studio (.net 4/VB).  I have a horizontal menu that starts out like this:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="False" 
IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal"  
meta:resourcekey="NavigationMenuResource1">
```

The site has several languages (hence the meta:resourcekey).  What I'm trying to accomplish is when a user hovers over one of the options, and the drop-down options appear, I'd like an arrow pointing to the right, letting them know that there are more options (submenus of submenus) if they hover over that particular option.

Here's an example of one of my menu options:

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/services/" Text="USS Services" 
meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResource4">
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="#" Text="Machine Vision Hardware" 
    meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResource20">
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/services/fixturing" Text="Fixturing" 
        meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResource21"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/services/specialmachines" Text="Special Machine 
        Build" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResource22"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/services/controlpanels" Text="Control Panels 
        &amp; Workstations" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResource23"/>
</asp:MenuItem>
```

If you hover over "USS Services", you'll see "Machine Vision Hardware", a submenu.  If you hover over "Machine Vision Hardware", you'll see Fixturing, Special Machine Build, and Control Panels & Workstations (submenus of submenus).  What I'd like to do is have an arrow on "Machine Vision Hardware" to let the user know that there are 3 different hardwares we manufacture if they hover over "Machine Vision Hardware".  If I just physically type in a >, it just looks sloppy.

Here's an example of what my menu currently looks like: [image: Here's what my menu currently looks like]

I don't have VS right now since my computer is in the shop, but I can hardcode it.  And I do have a tiny .jpg of a white arrow.  Does anybody know how to accomplish this?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Designer

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="true" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" RenderingMode="Default">
<DataBindings>
    <asp:MenuItemBinding TextField="MenuText"  ImageUrlField="ImgUrl" NavigateUrlField="destUrl" ToolTipField="tooltip" />
</DataBindings>
```

Css

```css
div.menu img
{
   float:right;
   width:15px;
   height:16px;
}
```

MenuItem

```css
<xsl:attribute name="ImgUrl">
        <xsl:value-of select="UrlImg"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
```